# jQuery Add an Element if Does Not Exist

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using jQuery to add content to an html form if it does not already exist - is there any way more succinct than this to test if a hidden field with a given value is already present in the form?

```
$("form").find("input[type='hidden'][value='" + $content.find("input[type='hidden']").val() + "']").length === 0
```

Comment: Not sure what `$content` contains, but `$content.find("input[type='hidden']")` could potentially match multiple elements, and then you would always get the value of the first that match. So your code will only validate against the first hidden-input in that context.

Comment: True - but I know that `$content` will only contain one hidden field. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using concatenation in jQuery selectors, you should be careful about escaping special chars (like quotes).
What if your input value is, for example, `Let's go`?
Your jQuery selector becomes `input[type='hidden'][value='Let's go']` and is invalid.

I'd rather go with `filter()` function:

```
$("form input[type='hidden']").filter(function() { return $(this).val() == $content.find("input[type='hidden']").val(); }).length === 0
```

Comment: Thanks - good point. I'd not considered the concatenation issue. Your end result is more verbose though, I was hoping for something succinct for a seemingly trivial operation. Maybe that is not possible in this case, but will see if there is anymore input before accepting.